# Handling Authentication Tokens in Next.js SSR: Maintaining RESTful Principles

Tags: rest, authentication, cookies, next.js, token

In a Next.js SSR environment, how can I manage and access tokens while maintaining RESTful principles? I understand that localStorage cannot be accessed server-side. Is there a recommended approach to handle tokens while keeping the API RESTful?

I have attempted to implement a RESTful API with authentication, considering the challenges of accessing tokens in a Next.js SSR environment. I tried to find a way to access tokens server-side and gained an understanding of storing and passing refresh tokens using cookies. I also considered whether using cookies for storing and passing authentication tokens is appropriate while maintaining a stateless API. However, I haven't reached a conclusion yet, and I'm curious if there is a recommended approach.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.